# On the adjoint operator on Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ be the space of all bounded linear operators $T: \mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$. For each $v\in \mathcal{H}$, denote $\hat{v}$ to be the linear operator $\mathcal{H}\ni u \mapsto \hat{v}(u) := \langle u, v\rangle$. The inverse map of $v \mapsto \hat{v}$ will be denoted $\hat{v}\mapsto \check{\hat{v}}$ (an upside down hat). If $\mathcal{H}^{*}$ is the dual space of $\mathcal{H}$ and $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, we define the operator $A^{\#}:\mathcal{H}^{*}\to \mathcal{H}^{*}$ by:
$$A^{\#}(T) := T\circ A \quad (T\in \mathcal{H}^{*})$$
that is, $(A^{\#}T)(v) := T(Av)$. Furthermore, the adjoint of $A$ is $A^{*}:\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ defined by:
$$A^{*}v := \check{A^{\#}\hat{v}} \quad (v\in \mathcal{H})$$
Now, I proved that if $v, w \in \mathcal{H}$ and $A^{*}$ is the adjoint of $A$, it follows that:
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle v, A^{*}\omega\rangle = \langle Av, \omega\rangle \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}

Now, my book says that it is generally easier to compute adjoints using the preceding result rather than its definition. According to the author: "This is possible because the inner product $\langle v, A^{*}\omega\rangle$ completely determine $\widehat{A^{*}\omega}$ and, hence, they completely determine $A^{*}\omega$, for all $\omega \in \mathcal{H}$. "

I think I understand the previous statement, but I'd like to confirm with you. I know that if $A^{*}$ is the adjoint of $A$, then it satisfies (\ref{1}), but, in order to use (\ref{1}) as a defining rule for adjoints I must show that if $B$ is such that $\langle v, B\omega\rangle = \langle Av, \omega\rangle$ than $B = A^{*}$. In other words, that (\ref{1}) completely defines the adjoint of a given operator $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. Is my reasoning correct?

Moreover, to prove that (\ref{1}) completely defines the adjoints, I should prove that the adjoint of a given bounded linear operator $A$ is unique (as I stressed before). But this is easy because, if not, then there exists another $B$ satisfying $\langle v, B\omega\rangle = \langle Av, \omega\rangle$ and, thus:
$$0 = \langle 0, \omega \rangle = \langle Av-Av, \omega\rangle = \langle Av, \omega\rangle -\langle Av, \omega \rangle = \langle v, (A^{*}-B)\omega\rangle$$
and, because the above identity follows for all $v,\omega \in \mathcal{H}$, we must have $A^{*}=B$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Sounds pretty good to me!  However, a line in a famous Bob Dylan song says “Your loyalty is not to me but to the stars above”. A Mathematician's interpretation of this would be that you should strive to fully convince yourself of the truths you find, relying less and less on other people's opinion!